# Use IEnumerable or specific type to return

Tags: c#, collections, return, ienumerable

I'm trying to write a method which will give me a HashSet collection, then I can use Contains() method to check something based on the time complexity of Contains() for HashSet is O(1). Here is a simple example:
I wrote two methods, the only difference is the return type. GetNamesHashSet() returns the specific HashSet, GetNames() returns IEnumerable to make it generic. Since there's dynamic binding, both will return HashSet at run time due to I initialize a HaseSet variable inside both methods. At compile time, we can see GetNames() should return an IEnumerable. Though, we could declare a variable aSet and call other methods which HashSet inherits from other interface. So both will give us whatever we need. Since the method is inaccessible to users, what they know if from interface is only the output and input.

My question is:

1. The purpose is to use HashSet's Contains() method by calling the GetNames() method. Once the GetNames() method returns a HashSet to caller, we can call the Contains() method. So which way is better for this scenario? Return IEnumerable or HashSet when we write the GetNames() method?
2. If I return IEnumerable(See below code example of GetNames() method), why can we call aSet.Contains() by declaring variable aSet in main method?Since it is dynamic binding, so once we declare like var aset = person.GetNames(), the type of aset is IEnumerable, IEnumerable only has a method GetEnumerator(), why aset has a method Contains()?

---

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person() { Name = "a", Age = 20 };
        HashSet<string> namesSet = person.GetNamesHashSet();
        if (namesSet.Contains(person.Name)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
        }

        var aset = person.GetNames(); 
        if (aset.Contains(person.Name)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetNames();
    HashSet<string> GetNamesHashSet();
}

public class Person :IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
        for (char c = 'a'; c < 'g'; c++)
        {
            set.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        return set;
    }

    public HashSet<string> GetNamesHashSet()
    {
        HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        for (char c = 'a'; c < 'g'; c++)
        {
            hashSet.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        return hashSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are exposing this to the outside world, then the ideal return type is [`ImmutableHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1). This is available in .Net Core and can be used in .Net Framework with a NuGet package. If you can't or don't want to add a new dependency (which is reasonable), returning `IReadOnlyCollection` is the next best choice.

In any case the effect is the same: you return the most specific type you can which does not allow the user to modify the collection. This is important because you ideally want to cache the collection you create and return the same object every time the method is called, instead of regenerating it every time as you currently are. `HashSet.Contains`  is fast because `HashSet.Add` is slow!

By returning a writeable collection you are also implying that modifying the collection will in some way affect the `Person` object, which is not the case. Your API is clearer and simpler if you return something read-only.

Regarding calling "Contains" on `HashSet` vs. `IEnumerable` (or indeed `IReadOnlyCollection`), this is the same thing. Before starting its own test the `Enumerable.Contains` method checks whether the source object implements `ICollection.Contains` and simply forwards the call.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and explanation. I'm confused no matter what we return such as HashSet(IEnumerable, IReadOnlyCollection), they all derive from System.Collection.Generic package and implement interface IEnumerable which has only one method named "GetEnumerator()", and the Enumerable class derives from System.Linq package, even it implements the IEnumerable, it also means implement the GetEnumerator method. Why is there a Contains() method to be used?

Comment: You got lost somewhere there: `System.Linq.Enumerable` is a static class which doesn't implement any interfaces at all. It exists to provide extension methods, including `Enumerable.Contains`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods